# How to learn irrelevant words in an information retrieval system?

Tags: nlp, recommender-system, word-embeddings

Right now my recommender system for information retrieval uses word embedding stogether with Tfidfs weights like written here:
http://nadbordrozd.github.io/blog/2016/05/20/text-classification-with-word2vec/

Using Tfidf improves results. But I have the problem that irrelevant keywords (high frequent words) still have a large impact.
Can I learn a system such that it learns on which words to pay attention - preferred in an unsupervised way?

What can you suggest for a better information retrieval using word embedings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are working with TF-IDF then it's important to experiment with `min_df` and `max_df` parameter. I guess you are on Python since you linked a Python tutorial. Here is the TF-IDF [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html) and the related text to the above parameters.

> **max_df : float in range [0.0, 1.0] or int, default=1.0** When building the vocabulary ignore terms that have a document frequency
>   strictly higher than the given threshold (corpus-specific stop words).
>   If float, the parameter represents a proportion of documents, integer
>   absolute counts. This parameter is ignored if vocabulary is not None.
>
> **min_df : float in range [0.0, 1.0] or int, default=1** When building the vocabulary ignore terms that have a document frequency strictly
>   lower than the given threshold. This value is also called cut-off in
>   the literature. If float, the parameter represents a proportion of
>   documents, integer absolute counts. This parameter is ignored if
>   vocabulary is not None.

You might find several rules of thumb on the web. Some of them suggest using a flat number on the `min_df` close to 5-7 documents and a percentage on the `max_df` about 80-85%. Maybe even lower. With this, you will be able to get rid of garbage, misspelt or unwanted tokens. Keep in mind that you need to try different combinations to get the right balance in your model.